# Using taxonomy & Views to create a sport Position Table.

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, database

I'm trying to create a new website for my Football Club. Its supposed to have 7 different divisions (or leagues) and 2 different seasons.
I use taxonomy to create de vocabulary "divisions" and then add... terms.
Then  I tried to do the same with seasons and It worked, but the problem is when I try to create (with views) a position table of each division.

I don't know why if I add two or more fields for each team
i.e. 
Team: Barcelona Season:Spring   Division(league): Premier. 
Team: Madrid   Season:Spring   Division(league): Premier.

Game: Barcelona VS Madrid
Winner: Madrid.

In the positioning table, it shows the double of values that its supposed to show but if I do not add any taxonomy or just one, it works well.
I do not where could be the problem.

I use the module "League: Online Tournament Manager".

This is a real example: Polish my Paul have the same numbers of games but the team has 2 taxonomys (Division & Season) and shows double of values and Changping Yeya has only Division taxonomy and shows the real (true) values.

[image]

Comment: I don't know that module at all but try Distinct under Advanced>Other>Query Settings in your view.